EventHubValidationErrorFound mapping does not exist
I got this error when I deployed the template and parameter below:
Error:
Code: EventHubValidationErrorFound
Message: [BadRequest] Validation Errors found: mapping does not exist
Basically what I am trying to do is to create a data connection Even Grid on a given Kusto cluster using ARM templates deployment.
I have this ARM template:
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "kustoclusterName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "kustoDbName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "dataFormatType": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "json"
    },
    "kustoDataConnectionsName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "subscriptionId": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[subscription().subscriptionId]"
    },
    "resourceGroup": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().name]"
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]"
    },
    "dpuMI": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "kind": {
      "type": "string",
      "allowedValues": [
        "EventHub",
        "EventGrid"
      ]
    },
    "eventHubNamespace": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "eventHub": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "eventHubSubscriptionId": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[subscription().subscriptionId]"
    },
    "eventHubResourceGroupName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().name]"
    },
    "consumergroup": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "$Default"
    },
    "storageAccountName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "mappingRuleName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "tableName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "dataFormat": {
      "type": "string",
      "allowedValues": [
        "JSON",
        "MULTIJSON",
        "CSV",
        "PARQUET"
      ]
    },
    "description": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": ""
    }
  },
  "variables": {},
  "resources": [
    {
      "condition": "[equals(parameters('kind'), 'EventHub')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Kusto/clusters/databases/dataConnections",
      "apiVersion": "2021-08-27",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('kustoclusterName'), '/', parameters('kustoDbName'), '/', parameters('kustoDataConnectionsName'))]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "kind": "[parameters('kind')]",
      "properties": {
        "managedIdentityResourceId": "[parameters('dpuMI')]",
        "eventHubResourceId": "[resourceId(parameters('eventHubSubscriptionId'), parameters('eventHubResourceGroupName'), 'Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/eventhubs', parameters('eventHubNamespace'), parameters('eventHub'))]",
        "consumerGroup": "[parameters('consumergroup')]"
      },
      "tags": {
        "Version": "0.0.0.0",
        "Description": "[parameters('description')]"
      }
    },
    {
      "condition": "[equals(parameters('kind'), 'EventGrid')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Kusto/clusters/databases/dataConnections",
      "apiVersion": "2021-08-27",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('kustoclusterName'), '/', parameters('kustoDbName'), '/eg', parameters('kustoDataConnectionsName'))]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "kind": "[parameters('kind')]",
      "properties": {
        "ignoreFirstRecord": "[equals(parameters('dataFormat'), 'CSV')]",
        "storageAccountResourceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName'))]",
        "managedIdentityResourceId": "[parameters('dpuMI')]",
        "eventHubResourceId": "[resourceId(parameters('subscriptionId'), parameters('resourceGroup'), 'Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/eventhubs', parameters('eventHubNamespace'), parameters('eventHub'))]",
        "consumerGroup": "[parameters('consumergroup')]",
        "tableName": "[parameters('tableName')]",
        "dataFormat": "[parameters('dataFormat')]",
        "blobStorageEventType": "Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated",
        "mappingRuleName": "[parameters('mappingRuleName')]"
      },
      "tags": {
        "Version": "0.0.0.0",
        "Description": "[parameters('description')]"
      }
    }
  ]
}

Parameter:
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "0.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "eventHubNamespace": {
      "value": "cpcnx-ehns-adlsv2tokusto-test01"
    },
    "eventHub": {
      "value": "cpcnx-eh-cds-storeingest-adxingest-dbingest-test01"
    },
    "consumergroup": {
      "value": "dpucg"
    },
    "kustoclusterName": {
      "value": "cpcnx-adx-test01"
    },
    "kustoDbName": {
      "value": "ingest"
    },
    "kustoDataConnectionsName": {
      "value": "cdsstoreingestadxingestdbingest"
    },
    "eventHubSubscriptionId": {
      "value": "{subId}"
    },
    "eventHubResourceGroupName": {
      "value": "cpcnx-test-test01"
    },
    "dpuMI": {
      "value": "/subscriptions/{subId}/resourceGroups/{regGroup}/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/cpcnx-pipmi-test01"
    },
    "kind": {
      "value": "EventGrid"
    },
    "storageAccountName": {
      "value": "cpcnxsaingesttest01"
    },
    "mappingRuleName": {
      "value": "EHCPCDevices_FastStream_Mapping"
    },
    "tableName": {
      "value": "EHCPCDevices_FastStream"
    },
    "dataFormat": {
      "value": "PARQUET"
    }
  }
}


On which platform you are executing this code!

EV2 is deploying this ARM template, but it would be the same as running on Deploy a custom template in Azure portal.

Ok working on it. @Guilherme Matheus

@Jahnavi were you able to find the reason? I was not able to find still

I am trying to figure out the issue. @Guilherme Matheus

Have you tried using event hub data connections. @Guilherme Matheus


Validation Errors found: mapping does not exist:

Check below steps to resolve the error "Mapping does not exist":

Make sure that the mapping rule existed in the specific table you are using in the ARM template.
Check if that the mapping rule has been created successfully in the Kusto database and existed in the specific Kusto cluster.
Also verify the cluster, database and data table names are correctly given according to their existence without any conflict.

Run below query in the Kusto explorer query editor to verify that the mapping rules actually existed or not in the Kusto database.
.show  table  lattable  ingestion  parquet  mappings


If nothing from the above resolves the issue, create a new ingestion mapping rule with the required data format by referring to the mapping formats available in Kusto explorer and redeploy the template with the modified parameter names.

Your code looks good for the requirement. Referring to this MSDoc ARM template, I have created a data connection between Azure event grid and a data explorer. It was successfully deployed as shown.
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "eventhubnamespace": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "cpcnx-ehns-adlsv2tokusto-test0",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "event hub namespace name."
            }
        },
        "eventhubname": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "cpcnx-eh-cds-storeingest-adxingest-dbingest-test01",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "event hub name."
            }
        },
        "consumergroup_default_name": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "$Default",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "consumer group of the event hub."
            }
        },
        "storageaccount": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "caronewperfdiag162",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "storage account name"
            }
        },
        "kustocluster": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "cpcnx-adx-test0"
        },
        "kustodb": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "ingest",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "database"
            }
        },
        "kustotable": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "lattable",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "table"
            }
        },
        "mappingRuleName": {
          "type": "string",
          "defaultValue":"Mapping1"
       },
        "dataformat_type": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "PARQUET",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "data format"
            }
        },
             "databaseRouting_type": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "Single"
        },
        "dataconnections_kustodc_name": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "kustodcnew",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "data connection to create"
            }
        },
        "subscriptionId": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "[subscription().subscriptionId]",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "subscriptionId of the resources"
            }
        },
        "resourceGroup": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().name]",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "resourceGroup of the resources"
            }
        },
        "location": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Location"
            }
        }
    },
    "variables": {
    },
    "resources": [{
            "type": "Microsoft.Kusto/Clusters/Databases/DataConnections",
            "apiVersion": "2022-02-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('kustocluster'), '/', parameters('kustodb'), '/', parameters('dataconnections_kustodc_name'))]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "kind": "EventGrid",
            "properties": {
                "managedIdentityResourceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Kusto/clusters', parameters('kustocluster'))]",
                "storageAccountResourceId": "[resourceId(parameters('subscriptionId'), parameters('resourceGroup'), 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageaccount'))]",
                "eventHubResourceId": "[resourceId(parameters('subscriptionId'), parameters('resourceGroup'), 'Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/eventhubs', parameters('eventhubnamespace'), parameters('eventhubname'))]",
                "consumerGroup": "[parameters('consumergroup_default_name')]",
                "tableName": "[parameters('kustotable')]",
                "dataFormat": "[parameters('dataformat_type')]",
                "mappingRuleName": "[parameters('mappingRuleName')]",
                "databaseRouting": "[parameters('databaseRouting_type')]"
            }
        }
    ]
}

Output:



Hi Jahnavi, thanks for answering this. Can you share how you created the mapping? Did you create first before deploying the template right? I think that's where I am stuck.

Do I need to create .create-or-alter table CPCDevicesEH_FastStream ingestion parquet mapping?

Yes haven't you done that before? @GuilhermeMatheus

Have you tried the above one. @GuilhermeMatheus

I haven't done this before, but I have this mapping that was working with json: .create-or-alter table CPCDevicesEH_FastStream ingestion json mapping 'CPCDevicesEH_FastStream_Mapping' '[{"column":"DPUData__IngestedTimestamp","path":"$.DPUData__IngestedTimestamp"}...]'

I was able to create the connection using JSON instead of PARQUET, that's why I am asking about the mapping.

Do you PARQUET mapping creation code? @GuilhermeMatheus
